# Run Valgrind from GNU Make

Tags: c, valgrind, gnu-make

I would like to have possibility to run Valgrind by using GNU Make.

Here is my simple makefile:

```
CC = gcc 
valg = /usr/bin/valgrind
LIBS = -lncurses -lpanel -lmenu


out: main7.c
    $(CC) main7.c -o out $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS) 

.PHONY: cl val 

val:
    $(valg) --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck ./out    

cl:
    rm out
```

How should I redefine my makfile to run Valgrind by a using command **make val**?

Comment: Your question is unclear: what happens when you run `make val`? Any error message? This should work.

Comment: Should be working as is, but change `val:` to `val: out` so that it will build `out` automatically if out's out of date.

Comment: There is an output message "Make: nothing to do in 'val'".

Comment: Added `val: out` does not help...

Comment: This is valid makefile. Double-check your makefile for special symbols. Ensure file 'val' doesn't exists in your directory. If problem persists, please add make's version and several latest lines of `make -d val`.

Comment: Ok, I have created a makefile with the same content one more time. For my surprise it works. The above makefile is valid and now it works on my pc too. Thanks for all help.

Comment: I think you are on the wrong way using valgrind .Why would you like to  exec valrgind when you are compling?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use valgrind to check if my program dosn't have memleaks, so I use it in a way that is presented above.

Comment: Good that you found an answer. Maybe you could post that as and answer. Or delete the entire question so this doesn't continue to show up as an unanswered question. Thanks.